# Gradle to spawn off multiple wars

Tags: java, gradle, war

I am working on a bunch of projects that will eventually be consolidated into one massive overarching parent project (per the direction of management).  I've been tasked to use Gradle to see if we can consolidate all 7 projects into one, but when the parent project is built, to have 7 separate, independent wars created.

Here is the proposed project structure:

```
ParentProject
  - src/main/java/Controllers
      - project A
           - setupController.java
      - project B
           - setupController.java
      - project C
           - setupController.java
  - src/main/java/Models
      - project A
           - model.java
      - project B
           - model.java
      - project C
           - model.java
  - src/main/webapps
      - parent_project
           - web.xml
           - css
              - common.css
              - projectA.css
              - projectB.css
              - projectC.css
           - js
               - common.js
               - projectA.js
               - projectB.js
               - projectC.js
```

When a developer runs the build script it should create 3 independent war files (projectA.war, projectB.war & projectC.war)

Here is projectA's expected archive content:

```
ProjectA.war
    - src/main/java/Controllers
       - setupController.java
    - src/main/java/Models
       - model.java
    - src/main/webapps
       - web.xml
       - css
          - common.css
          - projectA.css
       - js
          - common.js
          - projectA.js
```

I'm new to Gradle and I am looking to see if:

1. Gradle can do this?
2. Are there any good resources proving this out?

Comment: Keep the projects separate, but put them all in subdirectories of a parent project.  You can have a parent `build.gradle` file, which triggers a `build.gradle` file for each child project.

Comment: What's the rationale for smushing everything together?

Comment: The problem resides in that all the projects could potentially share resources (models, DAO's, jsp's, css, js, etc).  We would like to be able to reuse these components in each of the projects without having to copy the files from one project to the other

Comment: make a library project for your shared stuff, project C, and include it as a dependency in A and B.

Comment: @Armand - Can you explain what you mean by 'library project'?  If you look at the code snippets above I dont believe a traditional library project can handle this.

They are looking for dynamically building a war based upon which project you're looking to deploy.  In the example above your choices are to build projectA, projectB or projectC.  So if I am building projectA, it's code base will *NOT* contain any code from projectB or projectC, except for the code within the 'common' package

Comment: Sorry, I should have called my library project `project D` in my example - forgot that you'd already defined `Project C`.  If a lib project will not help, then I'm not able to understand the question in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, gradle can do this
2. Possibly not - it doesn't look like a great idea

A more idiomatic approach might be to make a super project with subprojects:

```
ParentProject
  - build.gradle
  - project A
    - build.gradle
    - controllers/
    - models/
    - webapps/
  - project B
    - build.gradle
    - controllers/
    - models/
    - webapps/
  - ...
```

Comment: The problem resides in that all the projects could potentially share resources (models, DAO's, jsp's, css, js, etc).  We would like to be able to reuse these components in each of the projects without having to copy the files from one project to the other